# Eclipse Maven Project Calling Class in Another Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have test class and want to instantiate the source class but i get error because the source class reference is not recognized in tester class.  I create project using Eclipse with maven.

Source class:

--myTest/src/main/java/myTest

```
   HelloWorld.java
```

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public String sayHello()
    {
        System.out.println("");
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Test class:

--myTest/src/test/java/testing

```
   GreeterTest.java
```

```
import main.java.myTest.HelloWorld; //error here

public class GreeterTest {
    public void greeterSaysHello() {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();//error here
    }
}
```

Configuration file:
POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>learningJUnit</name>
  <description>This is just for exploring to write test</description>

  <build>
  <sourceDirectory>srcs</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <source>1.8</source>
           <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: are you getting a compilation error ?

Comment: Yes it's compiler error. When I click on Save All button then I look at Eclipse output window below at Markers tab and one of the errors say "HelloWorld cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: get rid of the `<sourceDirectory>srcs</sourceDirectory>` in your pom.xml

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd thank you.  after removing that <sourceDirectory>, the error goes away.